# How can I adjust text size of the interface in Blender 2.8?

Tags: interface, windows

I have seen previous questions that say the text size can be set by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.
However, when I press these keys it doesn't seem to do anything at all.

I am using Blender 2.8 and Windows 10

How can I adjust text size of the interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*). There are two options that allow you to change the font size.

You can adjust the overall size of fonts and widgets using the *Resolution Scale* in the *Interface* tab.

[image: Interface tab]

Alternatively if you want to change the font size without affecting the size of icons and widgets, you can modify the theme's font size in the *Theme* tab under *Text Style*. There you can adjust the size using the *Points* option for panel titles, widgets and widget labels separately.

[image: Theme tab]

Comment: Thanks very much.  That's worked fine

Comment: @GrahamTranfield Great! If my answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted using the checkmark next to it.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I only just saw your comment.  I've done it now

Comment: @GrahamTranfield No problem. You're aware that you've selected moonboots answer as accepted though? That's fine if you intended to do that, I was just a bit confused because your reply made it look like you wanted to accept my answer.

Comment: @Robert Sorry,  I didn't understand the system.  I thought that I was able to click both and did not realise that unaccepted yours.  I have now clicked yours as it was the first and more comprehensive answer

Answer (score 0):

In *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Themes* > *Text Styles*.

Also, if you want to increase the size of the whole interface, *Edit* > *Preferences* > *Interface* > *Display* > *Resolution Scale*.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution too